# ul dropdown list disappears when clicking inside

Tags: jquery, html-lists

Quite a few good posts on this but none seemed to help.  I have a very simple drop down list which annoyingly closes when the list is clicked.  I'm suspecting it's to do with the way I've structured the list, but I can't get my head around it.  I've tried the usual

```
e.stopPropagation() and also
$(".cb-dropdown-wrap:not('.cb-dropdown')").on("click", function(e) {}
```

I strongly suspect I'm doing something stupid - please help!
Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tzxhryeu/

```
  $(".cb-dropdown-wrap").on("click", function(e) {

  if ($(".cb-dropdown").is(':visible')) { //alert('i can see it') 
    $(this).find("ul.cb-dropdown").slideUp();
    console.log(this)
  } else { //alert('No see it')
    $(this).find("ul.cb-dropdown").slideDown();
    console.log(this)
  }



<div class='cb-dropdown-wrap'>Select province

  <ul class='cb-dropdown'>
    <li class='IntroRow'>Intro container</li>
    <li class='active'>Option 3</li>
    <li class='active'>Option 4</li>
    <li class='active'>Option 5</li>
  </ul>

</div>



.cb-dropdown-wrap {
  /*bottom: 6px; */
  width: 200px;
  padding: 3px 0 3px 0;
  color: grey;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  outline: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.cb-dropdown {
  border: 1px solid red;
  cursor: default;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 6px;
  padding: 0 10px 10px 5px;
  display: none;
  outline: none;
}

.cb-dropdown li {
  margin: 10px 0 0 5px;
  /* padding: 5px 10px; */
  width: 280px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ul dropdown list disappears when clicking inside because you do not consider the [event target element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).

In order to close the drop-down only when you click on an **li active** or the **div cb-dropdown-wrap** you can test the event target element:

```js
$(".cb-dropdown-wrap").on("click", function(e) {
    var t = $(e.target);
    // test the target
    if (t.is(':not(.cb-dropdown-wrap)') && t.is(':not(.cb-dropdown li.active)')) {
        return;
    }
    if ($(".cb-dropdown").is(':visible')) {
        $(this).find("ul.cb-dropdown").slideUp();
    } else {
        $(this).find("ul.cb-dropdown").slideDown();
    }
});
$('li.active').on('click', function(e) {
    console.log('-->' + this.textContent)
})
```

```css
/* Top narrow container */
.cb-dropdown-wrap {
    /*bottom: 6px; */
    width: 200px;
    padding: 3px 0 3px 0;
    color: grey;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    outline: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid green;
}

/* Style long dropdown container */
.cb-dropdown {
    border: 1px solid red;
    cursor: default;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 6px;
    padding: 0 10px 10px 5px;
    display: none;
    outline: none;
}

/* Style for ALL li's inside dropdown */
.cb-dropdown li {
    margin: 10px 0 0 5px;
    /* padding: 5px 10px; */
    width: 280px;
}

/* Style Intro row */
.cb-dropdown li.IntroRow {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    height: 50px;
}

/* Style 'li active' elements ONLY  */
.cb-dropdown li.active {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background: #ececec;
}

.cb-dropdown li.active:hover {
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='cb-dropdown-wrap'>Select province

    <ul class='cb-dropdown'>
        <li class='IntroRow'>Intro container</li>
        <li class='active'>Option 3</li>
        <li class='active'>Option 4</li>
        <li class='active'>Option 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Much appreciated @gaetanoM.  I would never have considered the event target so great to learn this.